# Regression coefficient

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

Suppose, I have a regression equation.

$$Volatility = \alpha \times Exp. Loss + \beta \times Exp. Loss^2$$

This equation is based on a pool of data including two types of segments (say high risk loans and low risk loans).

After the regression analysis, I have $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Can I use these same $\alpha$ and $\beta$ coefficients for the two segments separately (say segment 1 and segment 2):

$$Volatility_1 = \alpha \times Exp. Loss_1 + \beta \times Exp. Loss_1^2$$
$$Volatility_2 = \alpha \times Exp. Loss_2 + \beta \times Exp. Loss_2 ^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the answer would be "no."  You should jointly estimate $$V_1=\alpha_1E(\mathcal{L_1})+\beta_1E(\mathcal{L_1})^2$$ and 
$$V_2=\alpha_2E(\mathcal{L_2})+\beta_2E(\mathcal{L_2})^2.$$  But since it sounds like they are part of the same system, there are a couple of other choices you could make as well that would improve information quality.

For example, you could estimate pooled volatility first, as $$V_p=\alpha_pE(\mathcal{L})+\beta_pE(\mathcal{L})^2$$ to get prior distributions over $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2$ and calculate the Bayesian point estimate.  Additionally, you could calculate the pooled volatility without conditioning on the expected loss variable as a noisy prior for the $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s.  Either of these would be an empirical prior.

In addition, if asset 1 is low risk and asset 2 is high risk, it is not too dangerous to assume that $V_2\ge{V_1}$.  You could structure the model so that $V_2$ is an additive function of $V_!$ to impose greater structure, such as including the constraint $$V_2=V_1+k,k\ge{0}$$.  Although it seems like a small thing, the added information would improve the estimators.

You could consider the joint estimate of $$V_1=\alpha_1E(\mathcal{L_1})+\beta_1E(\mathcal{L_1})^2+k_1,k_1\ge{0}$$ and $$V_2=\alpha_1E(\mathcal{L_1})+\beta_1E(\mathcal{L_1})^2+\alpha_2E(\mathcal{L_2})+\beta_2E(\mathcal{L_2})^2+k_1+k_2,k_2\ge{0}.$$

This choice would also have the advantage of appropriately mimicking the dynamics of the demand curve, since people would prefer less risk for the same price.  It would shrink the size of $\alpha_2,\beta_2$, though because some of the risk would be priced into the less risky asset's demand curve, giving it more of a marginal conceptualization.

If you choose this, you will want zero prior density on values that cannot rationally be negative.